# Elementary OS Loki 0.4 - Background Image not changing (all black)

Tags: wallpaper

I'm seeking assistance as I'm trying to use a custom background picture (not the ones that come by default) but once I select the picture the background goes all black and does not show the picture, now if I log out I do see the picture I selected on the login screen.

Is there a fix for this bug?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same bug. I tried to change the path to my wallpaper in the config file but that didnt work.

What DID work was: I copied my Wallapper in the directory where the default wallpaper is.

if you copy your wallpaper to /usr/share/backgrounds you can choose your wallpaper in the settings and it should work.